# Spark, how to print the query?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using pyspark

```
    df = self.sqlContext.read.option(
        "es.resource", indexes
    ).format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql").load()


    df = df.filter(
        df.data.timestamp >= self.period_start
    )
```

I'd like to see sql query version of `df` if possible.

something like `print(df.query)` to see something like `select * from my-indexes where data.timestamp > self.period_start`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out this piece of documentation for [pyspark.sql.DataFrame.explain](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.explain)
. `explain` prints the (logical and physical) plan to the console for debugging purpose.