# How do I print out a spark.sql object?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

I have a spark.sql object that includes a couple of variables.

```
import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports.LocalDate

val first_date = new LocalDate(2020, 4, 1)
val second_date = new LocalDate(2020, 4, 7)

val mydf = spark.sql(s"""
        select *
        from tempView
        where timestamp between '{0}' and '{1}'
""".format(start_date.toString, end_date.toString))
```

I want to print out `mydf` because I ran `mydf.count` and got 0 as the outcome.

I ran `mydf` and got back `mydf: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [column: type]`

I also tried `println(mydf)` and it didn't return the query.

There is this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56033068/spark-how-to-print-the-query), but it does not have the answer.

How can I print out the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way would be store your query into a **`variable`** then **print** out the variable to get the query.

- Use **`variable`** in `spark.sql`

---

**`Example:`**

**`In Spark-scala:`**

```
val start_date="2020-01-01"
val end_date="2020-02-02"
val query=s"""select * from tempView where timestamp between'${start_date}' and '${end_date}'"""
print (query)
//select * from tempView where timestamp between'2020-01-01' and '2020-02-02'

spark.sql(query)
```

**`In Pyspark:`**

```
start_date="2020-01-01"
end_date="2020-02-02"
query="""select * from tempView where timestamp between'{0}' and '{1}'""".format(start_date,end_date)

print(query)
#select * from tempView where timestamp between'2020-01-01' and '2020-02-02'

#use same query in spark.sql
spark.sql(query)
```

Comment: I tried the second option. I added "val " before the "query=" and the print out showed `select * from tempView where timestamp between'{0}' and '{1}'`

Comment: I think you are using **scala** interpreter then use `val query=s"""select * from tempView where timestamp between'${start_date}' and '${end_date}'"""`

Answer (score 1):

Here it is in PySpark.

```
start_date="2020-01-01"
end_date="2020-02-02"
q="select * from tempView where timestamp between'{0}' and '{1}'".format(start_date,end_date)

print(q)
```

Here is the onlnie running version: https://repl.it/repls/FeistyVigorousSpyware